# Converting strings with "hours, minutes, seconds" to HH:MM:SS

Tags: python, datetime

I have 3 example strings:

```
"1 hour, 27 minutes" 

"45 minutes,16 seconds"

"31 seconds"
```

I would like to have this output:

```
01:27:00

00:45:16

00:00:31
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: You want the second one to be 45:16 instead of 00:45:16? That will be extremely confusing if the number of minutes is less than 24. For example 12:30 in your case can be HH:MM or MM:SS. Are you really sure you want that?

Comment: Hi, actually yes you are right, I was just trying to fit in with previous code I have but I can change it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will parse your time string into a timedelta object then format the object as a string back to `(hh:mm:ss)` using [**`divmod`**](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/divmod.html)

```py
def format_time_str(time_string):
    timedelta_obj = sum(
        int(num) * {"hour": 3600, "minute": 60, "second": 1}[unit.rstrip("s")]
        for num, unit in [i.split() for i in time_string.split(",")]
    )
    
    hours, remainder = divmod(timedelta_obj, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    
    return f"{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}"
    
time_string_list = ["1 hour, 27 minutes", "45 minutes,16 seconds", "31 seconds"]
for time in time_string_list:
  print(format_time_str(time))
```

---

```
01:27:00
00:45:16
00:00:31
```

You can also use [**`re.findall()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs) approach:

```py
import re
def format_time_str(time_string):
    matches = re.findall(r"(\d+)\s*(hour|minute|second)s?", time_string)
    timedelta_obj = sum(
        int(num) * {"hour": 3600, "minute": 60, "second": 1}[unit]
        for num, unit in matches
     )
     ...
```